# How restart tomcat when it crushes down?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to develop a dynamic web project via Eclipse. It has tomcat 6. It crushes sometimes, and when I restart Eclipse and then run my project - it says:

```
 starting tomcat at localhost encountered a problem.
 Several ports(8005,8080) are already in use...
```

So, I think I need to stop tomcat from the previous project launch. I don't know how? Have any idea?

Comment: of course I could restart the whole system - but that is not an appropriate way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the terminal run this command:
sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:8005`